# How could I change my Interpreter from Python 3.8 to Python 3.9 in Visual Studio Code? [Resolved with answer]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, visual-studio-code, importerror

I know this is a many times questions but I still couldn't find the easiest way to resolve my question:

Recently I have got a import error for 'lxml' and I found that this error only occur when I use Visual Studio Code (VSC) but the script can execute perfectly fine when using 'python3' command in terminal
[image]

After I read several post from the forum, seems my questions is I should change my VSC parameter by using Python 3.9 instead of 3.8.

Demonstration in Terminal - Python3 works
[image]

Demonstration in VSC using 'Run Without Debugging'
[image]
Error: ImportError: cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml' (/Users/LSH/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/lxml/**init**.py)

When I check with my VSC, I could see that in the left bottom is using Python3.8.2 64 Bit.
So I am wonder once I change it to Python 3.9, then my current issue would be resolved?

[image]

Or should I update the python file?[image]
As I open the /usr/bin/python3, it is Python 3.8.2
[image]

Hope I could get the right answer soon :) Thanks all.

**@Update: After below suggestion, I tried to "Select Interpreter" by clicking Command + Shift + P, however, it shows the below options which I couldnt see Python 3.9, do you know where is the exact Python3.9 interpreter? (As all options point to /usr/bin/python3 which should be 3.8.2)**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this-
First click on Python 3.8.2 (your 4th picture). Then you will get an option to configure your python interpreter. Select the required version.

Comment: I tried the recommendation you stated as well, however, after I clicked , it just asks me to select the workspace. (either my current 'workspace' / 'entire workspace' can be selected)...

Comment: In your last picture(after update), there is an option to enter interpreter path. You can use that too.

Comment: do you know what is the Python 3.9 interpreter path is? I tried /usr/local/python3.9, when I execute in VSC and it says "The Python path in your debug configuration is invalid"

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. `ctrl/cmd + shift + p` to open command palette.
Step 2. Type `python: select interpreter`
Step 3. Click `python: select interpreter`
Step 4. Select a new interpreter from the drop down or type in the absolute path
Step 5. Celebrate

Comment: I have tried the recommendation you stated, could you please check my @Update message upon ?

Comment: Could be under `usr/local/bin` as well